# Combo Box IQueryable Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

I have recently changed a combobox binding from Observable Collection to a and IQueryable list, and at the moment the combobox correctly displays what I want it to in the selections, however I can't seem to set the default item of the combobox, it used to work with ObservableCollevtion, my code it below:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subject}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedSubject}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,303,0,0" Name="ddSubject" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235"  />
```

this code is in the ViewModel:

```
IQueryable<Subject> _subject;
public IQueryable<Subject> Subject { get { return _subject; } }
Subject _selectedSubject;
public DataAccess.Subject SelectedSubject
{
     get { return _selectedSubject; }
     set
     {
          if (value == _selectedSubject)
              return;
          _selectedSubject = value;
          person.subject = SelectedSubject.name;             
     }
}


void IniSelections()
{
    _subject = _sdc.Subjects;
    ....
    foreach(var r in Subject)
        if(r.name.Equals(person.subject))
        {
            _selectedSubject = r;
            break;
        }
    ....
    base.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSubject");
}
```

The IniSelection function is called in the Constructor.
I was wandering if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, or possibly point me in the direction to look to work out why it isn't working.

Thanks All :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set SelectedItem not SelectedValue.

Edit:
Let me point out a few things that strike me as unusual in your code. I'm not saying there's anything wrong, but maybe thinking about these will help.

1. *Subject* appears to be serving two purposes in the first two lines of your view model. At first I assumed it was some external data object that you were holding in an IQueryable. In the very next line it appears to be a property that returns an IQueryable of subjects. I see later in your SelectedSubject property you have to qualify what you're returning. I'm surprised you don't have to qualify in the IQueryable<>.  I would think using a different name for the property versus the underlying data object would be a good idea. Also it appears this could be reduced to just an automatic property.

   public IQueryable Subjects{get;}
2. I usually see the property change notification in the property setter. So as the last line of the SelectedSubject you could raise "SelectedSubject". Then in IniSelections() you would **not** set the private _selectedSubject you **would** call the public property setter SelectedSubject.
3. Are you checking that your if ever returns true?  You use of "person" confuses me, since your naming convention of _subject indicates member fields start with an underscore I would have assumed person was a local variable, but that doesn't jibe with how it's used in the SelectedSubject property.
4. I would rewrite this foreach using linq with the FirstOrDefault() method at the end something like 
   Subject.Where(r=>r.name == person.name).FirstOrDefault();
   Then check for the default case, othere wise use First() and handle the exception.
5. Depending on how .Equals is defined it's possible it doesn't return true when two DIFFERENT Subject objects have the same name. Of course I have to assume here that person is of type DataAccess.Subject